# check a key recusively in an array of objects to insert the data with a matching key

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object in the below format.

```js
let obj = [
  {
    children: [
      { children: [], data: { name: "aaa", id: "234" }, key: "234" },
      { children: [], data: { name: "bbb", id: "456" }, key: "456" },
      { children: [], data: { name: "ccc", id: "789" }, key: "789" },
    ],
    data: { name: "ddd", id: "123" },
    key: "123",
  },
  { children: [], data: { name: "eee", id: "411" }, key: "411" },
  { children: [], data: { name: "fff", id: "412" }, key: "412" },
]
```

I need to insert an array of objects (with similar structure above) in children array of ID:789, what is the better way to do this? I tried something like below. but i am able to check till 2nd level.

```js
  obj.map((emp) => {
    if (emp.data.id === idIwantToInsert) {
      emp.children.push(arrayofobjectsIwanttoInsert)
    } else {
      emp.children.map((citem) => {
        if (citem.data.id === idIwantToInsert) {
          citem.children.push(arrayofobjectsIwanttoInsert)
        }
      })
    }
  })
```

`What is the optimized way to check the key which can be deep inside in any of the array of objects`

Comment: `I tried something like below` which isn't recursive, like in your title. So, you are right, you need a recursive function.

Comment: Become friends with the `filter` function. You can dynamically iterate an array (or nested arrays by stacking these filters) and then return the collection as a modified value.

Comment: can you plz elaborate with an example